# React Native Expo IOS restriction on receiving HTTP requests

Tags: ios, react-native, http, expo

I've built an Express server and I'm having issues using the routes for IOS, I'm running the app on my IOS phone.

I have an Expo app and I added the infoPlist below under IOS in my app.json

```
"infoPlist": {
        "supportsTablet": false,
        "infoPlist": {
          "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads": {
            "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads": true
          }
        }
      },
```

I'm just trying to run the fetch below but I'm getting "Network Request Failed"

```
  useEffect(() => {
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/listing")
    .then((response) => setData(response))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error))
    .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);
```

Is there a current workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, iOS will block any request that's not encrypted using SSL. If you need to fetch from a cleartext URL (one that begins with http) you will first need to add an App Transport Security exception. If you know ahead of time what domains you will need access to, it is more secure to add exceptions only for those domains; if the domains are not known until runtime you can disable ATS completely. Note however that from January 2017, Apple's App Store review will require reasonable justification for disabling ATS. See Apple's documentation for more information.

On the react native site [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network)

In my opinion it is better to use https url to fetch